# Showing that the set of integers that can be expressed as tenth powers of integers is countable

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I'm trying to show that the set of all integers which are tenth powers of integers. Let $X = \{m \in \mathbb{Z} : \text{$m=k^{10}$ for some k}  \in \mathbb{Z}\}$. We want to show that $X$ is countable, i.e. that there exists an injection from $X$ to $\mathbb{N}$. I know that $X -\{0\} \subset \mathbb{N}$ so I extended the inclusion function from $X-\{0\}$ to $\mathbb N$ in order to construct an injective map. This is the function I came up with: $$f: X \rightarrow \mathbb N, x \mapsto f(x) = \begin{cases}
 x&\text{if}\, x\ne 0\\
 2&\text{if}\, x=0\\
\end{cases}$$

Now proving that this is an injection is quite trivial but I was wondering if there are any more easier injections from $X$ to $\mathbb N$.

Comment: Any infinite subset of a countable set is countable.

Comment: But $X$ here isn't an infinite subset since $0 \in X$.

Comment: How does the fact that $0\in X$ suggest that $X$ is not infinite?

Comment: It's a subset of $\mathbb Z$.... which is countable.

Comment: @lulu, I think he means it's not a subset of $\mathbb N$.

Comment: @fleablood  Oh, of course.  I was focussing on the "infinite" and not the "subset".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Now proving that this is an injection is quite trivial but I was wondering if there are any more easier injections from X to N."

Well $x\mapsto x + 1$.

Well, my first thought would be $f(x) = \sqrt[10]{x} + 1$. Not only an injection but a bijection.

IMO you are giving much more thought to this than it deserves.  Simply noting $X \subset \mathbb Z$ and $\mathbb Z$ is countable is enough.  So  as $\mathbb Z$ is countable, an injection into $\mathbb Z$ is as acceptable as an injection into $\mathbb N$.

After all, if $\phi: \mathbb Z\to \mathbb N$ is a bijection then the $\phi: X \subset \mathbb Z \to \phi(X)\subset \mathbb N$ is an injection.

(Which you *could* use to say $\phi: x\mapsto 2|x|$ if $x > 0$ and $\mapsto 2|x|+1$ if $x < 0$, so an natural injection would be $x \to 2x$ if $x > 0$ and $x\to 1$ if $x = 0$.  Which is ... silly.)

Answer (score 1):

A simple injection $X \to \mathbb N$ is given by $x \mapsto 2^x$ (a kind of [Gödel numbering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%C3%B6del_numbering)).

Answer (score 1):

Mapping each element of $X$ to its unique positive tenth root is an injection. But @lulu 's comment is a better reason: any infinite subset of a countable set is countable, hence the existence of a bijection.

Comment: Except $0$ is one of these so this is an injection to $\{0\}\cup \mathbb N$.  ... which really is not significant as both $\{0\}\cup \mathbb N$ and $\mathbb N$ are countable... but so is $\mathbb Z$ so the simple identity is an injection to $\mathbb Z$ and if $\phi:\mathbb Z \to \mathbb N$ is a bijection then $\phi(x)$ is an injection... lulu's comment cuts through all this unnecessary wheel spinning and get's to the heart lf the matter.